# Multiple .html to single csv with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, csv, beautifulsoup

I have 13,000 html files in a folder - I'm trying to get the data into a single csv file.

I believe I've managed to get most of it working - however seem to be having issues writing to the csv, regardless of what I try.

Here is my current code:

````
import re
import csv

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

path = r'C:/Users/Mx/Testing/Infod'

ext = '.htm'

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    
    if filename.endswith(ext):

        fullpath = os.path.join(path, filename)

        filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filename))[0]

        soup = BeautifulSoup(open(fullpath, encoding="utf-8"), 'html.parser')

        text = soup.get_text()

        ref = soup.find("td", text="Reference")
        pattern = re.compile(r'GBBTI\S{9}')
        IC = soup.find("b", text="Issuing country")
        cx = IC.findNext("td").contents
        SD = soup.find("b", text="Start date of validity")
        SDX = SD.findNext("td").contents 
        ED = soup.find("b", text="End date of validity")           
        EDX = ED.findNext("td").content
        NC = soup.find("b", text="Nomenclature code")
        NCX = NC.findNext("td").contents        
        CJ = soup.find("b", text="Classification justification")
        CJX = CJ.findNext("td").contents        
        L = soup.find("b", text="Language")
        LX = L.findNext("td").contents        
        POI = soup.find("b", text="Place of issue")
        POIX = POI.findNext("td").contents
        DOI = soup.find("b", text="Date of issue")
        DOIX = DOI.findNext("td").contents
        NAA = soup.find("b", text="Name and adress")
        NAAX = NAA.findNext("td").contents
        DOG = soup.find("b", text="Description of goods")
        DOGX = DOG.findNext("td").contents
        NK = soup.find("b", text="National keywords")
        NKX = NK.findNext("td").contents



        
        with open('names.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
            fieldnames = ['Ref', 'country', 'Start date of Validity', 'End date of validity', 'Nomenclature code', 'Classification justification', 'Language', 'Place of issue', 'Date of issue', 'Name and address', 'Description', 'keywords']
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)



            writer.writerow((soup.find('td', text=pattern)),cx, SDX, EDX, NCX, CJX, LX, POIX, DOIX, NAAX, DOGX, NKX) ```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
````

Comment: What issues are you facing ?

Comment: It won't save to the csv

Comment: Could you post what your CSV looks like after running this script ?

Comment: I suppose your CSV has only two rows after running this script. @MxMorrigan

Answer (score 1):

First of all one of the problems is that on every row you open the file for writing and actually by doing this in such way:

```
open('names.csv', 'w')
```

On every row, you rewrite the file (delete previous data and write new). To prevent this and speed up the whole process I would suggest opening it once before for loops (don't forget to close it).

Also as csv is really simple format I am not sure that it is really useful to use some sort of libraries to operate with it, an example of how  would do this:

```
import re
import csv

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

path = r'C:/Users/Mx/Testing/Infod'

ext = '.htm'

out_file = open('names.csv', 'w')
out_file.write(",".join(['Ref', 'country', 'Start date of Validity', 'End date of validity', 'Nomenclature code', 'Classification justification', 'Language', 'Place of issue', 'Date of issue', 'Name and address', 'Description', 'keywords']) + "\n") # Write your keys

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    
    if filename.endswith(ext):

        ...
        get your data
        ...

        out_file.write(",".join([ """pass here your values in corrent order""" ]) + "\n") # write your values separated by
out_file.close()
```